# Надо ли ставить кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли считать предложение "Пусть рассыплется..." прямой речью или хотя бы мыслями автора, и, соответственно, нужно ли ставить кавычки?

Что делает умный директор – немедленно покупает у изобретателя все права на изобретение и прячет патенты в несгораемый шкаф на вечное хранение. Пусть рассыплется любая, даже самая гениальная идея, если она угрожает чужим деньгам, чужой власти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно считать и, соответственно, МОЖНО ставить. Но лучше не надо.

Я бы поставил тире:

...прячет патенты в несгораемый шкаф на вечное хранение – пусть рассыплется любая, даже самая гениальная идея, если она угрожает чужим деньгам, чужой власти.

Comment: Я тоже думала про тире... Но, следуя этой логике, можно и оставить как есть и, соответственно, кавычки не ставить?.. Меня просто смущает то, что мысль заведомо отрицательная, и если не поставить кавычки, то можно подумать, будто автор эту точку зрения разделяет, а это не так.

Comment: Если не разделяет, то почему директор назван умным? Разделяет, разделяет. )))

Comment: ))))))))))))))

Answer (score 2):

Это не прямая речь, кавычки не нужны.
Тире ставить не нужно:оно уже есть в предложении. Ср.:"Что делает умный директор – немедленно покупает у изобретателя все права на изобретение и прячет патенты в несгораемый шкаф на вечное хранение - пусть рассыплется любая, даже самая гениальная идея, если она угрожает чужим деньгам, чужой власти". Неграмотно. Смысл теряется, интонация меняется; конструкция, обрамлённая тире,  выглядит как вставная конструкция, которой, увы,  нет.

Вариант постановки знаков:

***Что делает умный директор? Немедленно покупает у изобретателя все права на изобретение и прячет патенты в несгораемый шкаф на вечное хранение: пусть рассыплется любая, даже самая гениальная идея, если она угрожает чужим деньгам, чужой власти!***

Двоеточие в БСП ставится, если вторая часть предложения (у вас это сложноподчинённое предложение) поясняет первую или указывает на причину того, о чём говорится в первой части.

Answer (score 1):

Это несобственно-прямая речь.

На "Грамоте":

Сущность ее заключается в том, что в ней почти полностью сохраняются лексические и синтаксические особенности чужого высказывания, манера речи говорящего лица, эмоциональная окраска, характерная для прямой речи, но передается она не от имени персонажа, а от имени автора, рассказчика. Автор в этом случае соединяет мысли и чувства своего героя со своими, сливает его речь со своей речью. Этот прием часто используется в художественной литературе и публицистике, когда автору нужно показать своего героя как бы изнутри, дать читателю услышать его внутренний голос.

Например:

Николай Ростов отвернулся и, как будто отыскивая чего-то, стал смотреть на даль, на воду Дуная, на небо, на солнце. Как хорошо показалось небо, как голубо, спокойно и глубоко! Как ласково-глянцевито блестела вода в далеком Дунае! (Л. Толстой)

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки не ставятся, если прямая речь соответствует косвенной с тем же лексическим составом, без ее изменения. В вашем предложении та же ситуация. Ниманд прав: лучше тире. Т.к. после тире идет неожиданное присоединение.